# Do 最愛の人 and ダーリン mean the same thing?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, words

I looked up for the word "darling" and got two different answers and I just want to know if they both mean the same thing.

Comment: Depends on the context.  What are you trying to say?  Also, where did you look this up?  And what is your level of Japanese comprehension?